# How to obtain all 3 starters on Pokemon Fire Red/Leaf Green and have them as Original Trainer (OT) (Macbook VBA)?

Tags: emulation, pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

I am currently using an Apple M1 Ventura machine with a VirtualBoyAdvance.

How do I get all 3 starters (Bulbasaur, Charmander and Squirtle) with Original Trainer (OT) status on a game without using cheats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Outline

I have not used cheats, but made use of reusing saves at several points.

Also, I will be using Fire Red as the game I want to get all 3 starters on but this can easily reversed for Leaf Green.

### Hardward Used

- Apple M1 Ventura.
- Installed [VBA](https://visualboyadvance.org/download/) and copied it twice in Applications to create a "Player 1" and "Player 2".

### Steps

1. Create a save of Fire Red and Leaf Green.
2. Save Fire Red **just before** you choose your starting Pokemon.
3. Close the game.
4. Clone the save file to have a suffix e.g. " checkpoint.sav".
5. Play Leaf Green to a point at which you can trade with it.
6. Back on Fire Red, pick a starter, then play through to the point when you can catch a Pokemon and head to the Pokemon center.
7. Trade the starter over Leaf Green to a Pokemon you don't mind having deleted.
8. Save and close games.
9. Save games and check save files for odd suffixes e.g. "-1.sav" -> ".sav".
10. Delete Fire Red save and duplicate checkpoint and remove suffix.
11. Load up Fire Red and repeat steps 6-10.
12. At this point, you should have 2 starters with Fire Red's OT on Leaf Green.
13. After checking filename suffixes, then you can start Fire Red by copying the checkpoint and picking the final starter.
14. Connect to Leaf Green and trade back the original starters.
15. Check the filenames for weird suffixes afterwards and you should be complete.

### Tips

- **Play the games slowly and check for details** - the video I will post at the end of the section demonstrates this
- **Do close the games and check that they still work** - if you receive an odd error that the VBA cannot find your file, close VBA and re open and it should find it

Here is a video that shows *part* of the process for trading over starters to get original files: